# Get parent node name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to get the parent node name of the checked child node of ASP.net TreeView Control using jQuery/JavaScript ?

```
$('#<%=treeMeasures.ClientID%>').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
                        alert($(this).parent().text());
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to get the parent node use `$(this).parent().get(0)`

if you just need the tag name of the parent Element  try `$(this).parent().get(0).tagName`

Answer (score 0):

The `.parent()` function is used to access an elements immediate parent.

You can also use `.parents()` to access parent elements further up in the ancestry.

You can also include an optional parameter for a filter to a specific selector in either case.

Comment: I had tried .parent(). I am unable to retrieve the node name. Well I am putting the sample jquery I had done, which I wanted to retrieve the parent nodes name, in the above question

Comment: Well my issue is, I wanted to restrict dragging Parent Node from ASP.net TreeView control. I want to drag only child node

Answer (score 0):

Not really a jQuery guru, but if you need to access the id of the parent you could try using

```
 $(this).parent().attr('id')
```

Comment: I think he's looking for the dom attribute ".nodeName" and not the id.